# NSUserDefaults will not load data consistently

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a **tab-based application** and want to **reload data** each time I switch between the tabs. So I used `viewWillAppear:` which gets called but the data doesn't reload. Could this be a result of using lots of `[NSUserDefault]`'s?
Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self reloadData];
}

-(void)reloadData {

    //Loading all the data
    totalApples = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"totalApples"];
    [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f", totalApples] withExistingAttributesInLabel:self.applesLabel];

    applesPerSecond = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"applesPerSecond"];
    [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f", applesPerSecond] withExistingAttributesInLabel:self.applesPerSecondLabel];

    applesPerClick = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"applesPerClick"];
}
```

Comment: ViewWillAppear, silly me

Comment: Oh, so is there any obvious problem? ;-)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "but this only works half of the time"?

Comment: When I switch to the other tab it only reloads the Data if a wait a little bit, or if not about 50% of the time. (I have this code in both viewControllers)

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in viewWillAppear and verified that it is only called half of the times?

Comment: Ok, bad question. I should have checked. It gets called every time but the data doesn't reload every time. Could this be a result of me user lots of [NSUserDefaults]? I will change the thread

Comment: Are you calling `synchronize` when writing out the data to `NSUserDefautls`?

Comment: Uh, no.. :/ Have't ever seen it used. I just started coding really.

Comment: You shouldn't use user defaults to pass data between controllers, that's not what it's for. If you need the data (a small amount) to persist between launches of the app, then you should use user defaults.

Answer (score 2):

When using `NSUserDefaults` it is a good idea to call `-synchronize` after writing the data.

Take the following example:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:@100 forKey:@"SomeKey"];

[defaults synchronize]; //This will ensure data is written.
```

If you do not call this method the system periodically does. However it can lead the timing issues like you are probably experiencing.

Read more about `NSUserDefaults` and this behavior [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize).

**Update**

This question is losing its context now I think. Here is an updated method that you  posted below in the comments. It might be worth posting a follow up question since this is probably not an issue with `NSUserDefaults`.

Here at least for posterity is an example of using `NSUserDefaults` to write out data. I also updated your method to save *priceFarmHands* as a float because of the multiplication being performed. (It was being written out as an integer before and probably being truncated).

```
- (void)buyFarmhand {
    farmHands++;
    totalApples -= priceFarmHands;

    if(priceFarmHands < 1000) {
        priceFarmHands = priceFarmHands * 1.35;
    } else if(priceFarmHands < 10000) {
        priceFarmHands = priceFarmHands * 1.25;
    } else {
        priceFarmHands = priceFarmHands * 1.15;
    }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setFloat:priceFarmHands forKey:@"priceFarmHands"];
    [defaults setInteger:farmHands forKey:@"farmHands"];
    [defaults setDouble:totalApples forKey:@"totalApples"];

    [defaults synchronize];

    [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", priceFarmHands] withExistingAttributesInLabel:self priceFarmHandsLabel];
    [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", farmHands] withExistingAttributesInLabel:self.numberFarmhands];
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do this for loading data as well, because I am still experiencing this behaviour

Comment: According to the docs calling synchronize 'Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.' so calling `synchronize` before reading your data could help. If it doesn't then maybe your data isn't being written every time and you should ensure that the code that sets up your data is being called and no if statements are being skipped over.

Comment: @SHERRIECRANE can you show the code that is writing to user defaults? It could be as simple as not storing the values as `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: Also I just noticed you are retrieving the data as integers, but trying to format floats in the labels. Check the data types.

Comment: It works perfectly from one tab to the other, but the other way it doesn't pass over the data more than once

Comment: @Dan there are lots of bits of code but they all work like this: http://pastebin.com/G7rcKuEB

Comment: Updated answer, at this point it is unclear exactly what the issue is to me at least. Consider posting a follow up question. Sorry I was unable to help.

Comment: Should I just explain the issue in a different question and post all the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you create the NSUserdefault object, It should be created in the reloadData method, this should work:

```
-(void)reloadData {
    //Loading all the data
    NSUserDefaults *appleData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    totalApples = [appleData integerForKey:@"totalApples"];
    applesPerSecond = [appleData integerForKey:@"applesPerSecond"];
    applesPerClick = [integerForKey:@"applesPerClick"];

    //Set the labels text
    [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f", totalApples] 
                    withExistingAttributesInLabel:self.applesLabel];
    [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f", applesPerSecond] 
               withExistingAttributesInLabel:self.applesPerSecondLabel];
}
```

Also to help you troubleshoot this add some log to `viewWillAppear`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear called, reloadind data...");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self reloadData];
}
```