# Passing Data between tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am using NSUserDefaults to pass data between tabs in a tab-based app and the data is passed from 1 to 2 the first time and always works from 2 to 1 but, only from 1 to 2 the fist time. Both use viewWillAppear to call the reloadData method. Is it necessary for me to post all the code or is there anything specific that would most likely highlight the cause of the problem as I don't really want to post ALL my code!

Comment: Post the code where you add data to NSUserDefaults and access the data from NSUSerDefaults. When asking a question (just so you know), you only need to post relevant code. Example: your question is mainly regarding NSUserDefaults, so post all of the code that refers to, or has to do with NSUserDefaults.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of your own posts...
You were given all the info already:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673990/how-to-share-data-between-viewcontrollers-in-a-tabbed-application/18674586#18674586
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686007/nsuserdefaults-will-not-load-data-consistently

Comment: I was told to post a followup question because nobody solved the question

Comment: Sherrie, you asked this question before and [it was answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673990/how-to-share-data-between-viewcontrollers-in-a-tabbed-application). When this was pointed out to you, you said "there is a problem with the code which prevents the data being passed." Well, then, you should share your code in which you attempted to implement one of the solutions posted at that other question, but with which you had challenges.